# Can't create new bitmap from path

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm learning C# and trying to create a new Bitmap from image path, but an error keeps occurring.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'
```

this is my code:

```
string DesktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string imName = "p2.jpg";
string imPath = Path.Combine(DesktopPath, imName);
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(imPath);
```

It's important to note that the image is not big (450x300)

Comment: That will happen if the .jpg is not in a valid or recognized format, try with one you create yourself in mspaint, if that works investigate the validity of p2.jpg.

Comment: Did you check if the final constructed `imPath` indeed contains the correct path? Try doing a `File.Exists(imPath)` test before it. If it's correct, yea, you might want to add the image file so people can actually see what is in it.